# Bugs in ranking array in php

Tags: php, arrays, rank

I need a ranking system, and this is what I have.

```
<?php
$arr=array(10,11,4,2,10,3);
$rank = $arr;
rsort($rank);
foreach($arr as $sort) {                            
     echo $sort.' is ranking '.(array_search($sort, $rank) + 1).'<br>';
}
?>
```

The result I got is

```
10 is ranking 2
11 is ranking 1
4 is ranking 4
2 is ranking 6
10 is ranking 2
3 is ranking 5
```

The problem is, when I have 2 entries with the same values it skipped the next rank. The result I got above shows '10 is ranking 2' twice. But then it skipped to rank 4.

I need it to be like this.

```
10 is ranking 2
11 is ranking 1
4 is ranking 3
2 is ranking 5
10 is ranking 2
3 is ranking 4
```

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: or if want to include the number it was repeated you can do like this `<?php
$arr=array(10,11,4,2,10,3);
$rank = $arr;
rsort($rank);
foreach($arr as $sort) {       
 
 $index = array_search($sort, $rank);
 
     echo $sort.' is ranking '.($index + 1).'<br>';
 $rank[$index] = 'X'; //That indicates to your program you already
  //compared that position
}`

Comment: @iwaduarte i see. thank you. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.

Because you have `10` multiple times, `rsort` will map it multiple times.
If you want to do it your way, the original input cannot have multiple times the same input.

With [array_unique](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) you can solve this, so you will always have an unique input.

For example

```
$arr=array(10,11,4,2,10,3);
$rank = array_unique($arr); //This line have I changed
rsort($rank);
foreach($arr as $sort) {                            
     echo $sort.' is ranking '.(array_search($sort, $rank) + 1).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: you save me.. i really need to learn more about array. thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$arr=array(10,11,4,2,10,3);
$rank = $arr;
rsort($rank);

foreach($arr as $sort) { 
  if($sort <= 4){
       echo $sort.' is ranking '.(array_search($sort, $rank)).'<br>';
   }else{
      echo $sort.' is ranking '.(array_search($sort, $rank) + 1).'<br>';
   }
}
?>
```